# How to execute mqtt commands of Getconfig in android java

Tags: android, flutter, mqtt, face-recognition

{
"messageId": "ID:192.168.16.29-52757575754",
"Operator": "Getconfig-Ack",
"info": {
"facesluiceId": "1414414",
"Language": "0",
"DataBaseEnable": "1",
"IDcardType": "0",
"CardReaderType": "0",
"CardOpenDoorWay": "0",
"FaceDisplay": "1",
"LiveDetectType": "1",
"LiveDetectTimeBeg": "07:00:00",
"LiveDetectTimeEnd": "19:00:00",
"LiveThreshold": "90.000000",
"LiveFrameNum": "5",
"LedLightType": "1",
"LedTimeBeg": "19:00:00",
"LedTimeEnd": "07:00:00",
"LedBrightness": "20",
"LedDisableAfterSec": "30",
"LcdBLDisable": "0",
"LcdBLDisableAfterSec": "30",
"ScreenBrightness": "50",
"SceneSnap": "0",
"WebTimeOut": "10",
"result": "ok"
}
}

Now how can i execute commands that system will me the Gettconfig-Ack properly

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.